# My PHP Function isn't working

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

I'm having trouble with the following code. What it should do is echo cats.php followed by example.php but it's not echoing the example.php. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
$bookLocations = array(
    'example.php',
    'cats.php',
    'dogs.php',
    'fires.php',
    'monkeys.php',
    'birds.php',
);

echo $bookLocations[1];

function findfile($filenumber)
{
echo $bookLocations["$filenumber"];
}

findfile(0);
```

Comment: I fail to see why anyone would downvote this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i believe you may also need to declare the global variable in your function.

```
global $bookLocations;
```

Comment: don't disagree with you but given the function provided, that is the only way. Some of the suggestions to change the function declaration are also quite valid.

Comment: Thats another issue, tharkun. He could have mentioned that in his answer, but this is obviously what the GP was trying to do, so this is the correct answer.

Comment: no, it's not the correct answer! it's the wrong answer! the correct answer is to pass the array to the function!

Comment: you should really not accept this answer because you will help promoting bad practices! using globals is a bad practice in general!

Comment: woo guys, who is upvoting this? it is bad advise. period.

Comment: LOL, tharkun, calm down. :) Let him learn it the hard way. :P

Comment: I'm privatly calm :) but SO-ly agitated when obviously wrong answers are being accepted and upvoted ;)

Comment: Well, it'll solve his problem. At least for a little while. And hopefully encourage him to find out why global variables are bad.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing,

```
echo $bookLocations["$filenumber"];
```

to:

```
echo $bookLocations[$filenumber];
```

Edit*  To expand on Thomas's correct answer, instead of using global variables, you could change your method to:

```
function findfile($filenumber, $bookLocations)
{
    echo $bookLocations[$filenumber];
}
```

Comment: Indeed.  "thomas" has the right answer below.  You need to use global $foo; within your function.  It's a scoping issue.

Comment: Better try to `echo $bookLocations;`

Comment: @genio: that's bad advice, global variables are evil!

Comment: Heh dunno how I overlooked that.  Should probably just change to pass the array as a parameter and then use it that way.

Comment: +1 because this answer is clearly better than the current accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555521/my-php-function-isnt-working/1555541#1555541

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there are two issues.

#### Variable Scope

Your function doesn't know the array `$bookLocations`, you need to pass it to your function like so:

```
function findfile($filenumber, $bookLocations)
```

#### Array key

You don't want to wrap your array key in quotes:

```
wrong: $bookLocations["$filenumber"];
right: $bookLocations[$filenumber];
```

Comment: Because the array key is $filenumber not $filenumber wrapped in quotes. It is not a string but it is an integer.

Comment: This depends on PHP configuration. It is preferable to avoid parentheses, though.

Answer (score 1):

The  quotes in `"$filenumber"` turn your key into a string, when the keys to your array are all numbers.  You are trying to access `$bookLocations["1"]` when in fact you *want* to access `$bookLocations[1]` -- that is to say, `1` is **not** the same as `"1"`.  Therefore, like others have said, you need to get rid of the quotation marks around the key (and check your variable scope too).

Answer (score 1):

```
function findfile($filenumber)
{
  global $bookLocations;
  echo $bookLocations[$filenumber];
}
```

Good-style developers usually avoid global variables. Instead, pass the array to the function as the parameter:

```
function findfile($files, $filenum)
{
  echo $files[$filenum];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$bookLocations is out of scope for your function.  If you echo $filenumber you will see that it's in scope because you passed it in by value. However, there is no reference to $bookoLocations.

You should pass in $bookLocations

declaration: function findfile($filenumber, $bookLocations){
call: findfile(1, $bookLocations);

You could also to declare $bookLocations as global, but globals should be avoided if possible.